# Git Extension for Jdeveloper 11.1.1.4.0 11c

Tags: java, git, jdeveloper, git-extensions

I am trying to get Git extension for Jdeveloper 11c but i only see 
(Perforce, Dimensions, ClearCase, Team System VCS Extensions)
https://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/131167.xml
Is it available for this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a git extension available for 11.1.1.4. 
You can use any git client for your operating system you like.

Comment: Thank you, i just discovered that and i installed 11.1.1.9 then i found Git inside it.